# Help getting AJAX to update an edited comment in Rails 3 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I edit a comment that already exists and press 'save' - which in my jquery is clicking the `input#comment_submit`, it hides my edit form, and shows the list from the original state (i.e. before the update).

But if I refresh the page, it shows the updated comment - which shows me that the comment was actually updated via Rails. So not sure what's happening.

The final product I want is:

- Click edit. Enter updates to the comment.
- Click save. jQuery hides edit box, and shows the updated comment - without doing a full page refresh.

Here is the HTML for the comment:

```
<div class="comment-show"> 
   <div class="details"> 
    <span class="comment_name">Test</span> said
   </div> 
   <div class="uploads"> 
      <div class="upload-image" title="red-stripe-dark.jpg"><img alt="Red-stripe-dark" src="red-stripe-dark.jpg" /></div> 
      <div class="upload-image selected-image" title="red-stripe-original.jpg"><img alt="Red-stripe" src="red-stripe.jpg" /></div> 
      <div class="upload-image selected-image" title="red-stripe-red.jpg"><img alt="Red-stripe-red" src="red-stripe-red.jpg" /></div> 
      <div class="upload-image" title="red-stripe-bw.jpg"><img alt="Red-stripe-bw" src="red-stripe-bw.jpg" /></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="body"> 
      This is extremely ugly. WOW.Let's see if this works any at all.<br /> 
       <span class="timestamp">about 1 hour ago</span> 
      <div class="comment-buttons"> 
        <button class="comment-edit green awesome">Edit</button> 
        <button class="red awesome" data-destroy-url="/comments/28" data-destroy-title="Delete this comment?" data-compv-mapping="comments.destroy">Delete</button> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
</div>

    <div class="comment-form" style="display:none"> 

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comments/28" class="ajax-form" data-remote="true" id="comment-ajax-form-update" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /></div> 
<input id="comment_stage_id" name="comment[stage_id]" type="hidden" value="46" /> 
<input id="comment_user_id" name="comment[user_id]" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
<h3>Add a Comment</h3> 


<div> 
    <div class="uploads" > 
    <div class="hint">Select the images you are discussing</div> 

        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-dark.jpg" id="image-selector-141"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe-dark" src="red-stripe-dark.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" id="comment[uploads_ids][141]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="141" /> 
         </div> 
        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-original.jpg" id="image-selector-140"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe" src="red-stripe.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" checked="checked" id="comment[uploads_ids][140]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="140" /> 
         </div> 
        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-red.jpg" id="image-selector-139"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe-red" src="red-stripe-red.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" checked="checked" id="comment[uploads_ids][139]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="139" /> 
         </div> 
        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-bw.jpg" id="image-selector-138"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe-bw" src="red-stripe-bw.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" id="comment[uploads_ids][138]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="138" /> 
         </div> 
    </div> 

<textarea cols="40" id="comment_body" name="comment[body]" rows="10" style="width: 100%">This is extremely ugly. WOW. Let's see if this works any at all.</textarea>
    <div class="actions"> 
      <input class="green awesome" id="comment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" /> 
       <button class="comment-form-cancel red awesome">Cancel</button> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
   <br style="clear:both" /> 
  </form> 

</div> 
   </li> 
 </ul> 
 <div id="comment-form"> 

 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comments" class="ajax-form" data-remote="true" id="comment-ajax-form-create" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div> 
<input id="comment_stage_id" name="comment[stage_id]" type="hidden" value="46" /> 
<input id="comment_user_id" name="comment[user_id]" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
<h3>Add a Comment</h3> 


<div> 
    <div class="uploads" > 
    <div class="hint">Select the images you are discussing</div> 

        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-dark.jpg" id="image-selector-141"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe-dark" src="red-stripe-dark.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" id="comment[uploads_ids][141]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="141" /> 
         </div> 
        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-original.jpg" id="image-selector-140"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe" src="red-stripe.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" id="comment[uploads_ids][140]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="140" /> 
         </div> 
        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-red.jpg" id="image-selector-139"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe-red" src="red-stripe-red.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" id="comment[uploads_ids][139]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="139" /> 
         </div> 
        <div class="upload-image image-selector" title="red-stripe-bw.jpg" id="image-selector-138"> 
         <img alt="Red-stripe-bw" src="red-stripe-bw.jpg" /> 
        <input autocomplete="off" id="comment[uploads_ids][138]" name="comment[upload_ids][]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="138" /> 
         </div> 
    </div> 

<textarea cols="40" id="comment_body" name="comment[body]" rows="10" style="width: 100%"></textarea> 
    <div class="actions"> 
       <input class="green awesome" id="comment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Comment" /> 
     </div> 
      </div> 
     <br style="clear:both" /> 
     </form>
```

Here is the JS embedded on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('button.comment-edit').live('click', compv.comments.edit);
$('button.comment-form-cancel').live('click', compv.comments.editCancel);

$('div.actions input#comment_submit.green.awesome').live('click', compv.comments.updated);

$('#comment-ajax-form-update')
    .bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    //console.log("Updated comment");

});

$('#comment-ajax-form-create')
    .bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    compv.comments.updateView('comments', xhr);
    $('div.image-selector').each(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        element.children('input').attr('checked', false);
        element.removeClass('selected-image');
    });
});
```

Here are the related JS snippets:

```
   compv.comments.updated = function(event){
    var parentElement = $(this).parents("li");
    parentElement.find('div.comment-show').fadeIn("slow");
    parentElement.find('div.comment-form').fadeOut("slow");
}; 

    compv.comments.edit = function(event){
console.log("Clicked Edit");
var parentElement = $(this).parents("li");
parentElement.find('div.comment-show').hide();
parentElement.find('div.comment-form').show();
};

compv.comments.editCancel = function(event){
    console.log("Clicked Cancel");
    var parentElement = $(this).parents("li");
    parentElement.find('div.comment-show').show();
    parentElement.find('div.comment-form').hide();
};

compv.comments.updated = function(xhr){
    var parentElement = $(this).parents("li");
    parentElement.find('div.comment-show').fadeIn("slow");
    parentElement.find('div.comment-form').fadeOut("slow");
};

compv.comments.updateView = function(divPrefix, xhr){
var dataDiv = 'div#'+divPrefix;
if(xhr.responseText.length > 1){ 
    $(dataDiv + ' ul').append(xhr.responseText);
    $(dataDiv + ' ul li:last').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
}
};

var compv = {
    exists: true,
    tools: {
        exists: true,
        csrf_param: null,
        csrf_token: function() { },
        clientError: function() { }
    },
    comments: {
        exists: true,
        updateView: null,
        selectImage: null,
        upvote: null,
        edit: null,
        cancelEdit:null,
        downvote: null,
        showVotes: null,
        destroy: {
            success: null,
            error: null,
            dialog: 'comment-destroy-dialog'
        },
        getUploadID: function(element) {
            return $(element).parents("li").attr("data-upload-id");
        }
    },
    steps: {
        exists: true,
        selectFn: {},
        selectedClass: "selected-step",
        selectableClass: "selectable-step",
        selectedClient: {
            element: null,
            id: null,
            stepType: "client",
            ajaxSuccess: null
        },
        selectedProject: {
            element: null,
            id: null,
            stepType: "project",
            ajaxSuccess: null
        },
        selectedStage: {
            element: null,
            id: null,
            stepType: "stage",
            ajaxSuccess: null,
            getID: function() {
                return compv.steps.selectedStage.id;
            },
            displayCompare: function() {
                window.open($(this).attr('data-url'), "_blank");
            }
        },
        selectedUpload: {
            element: null,
            id: null,
            stepType: "image",
            primeUploadDisplay: null,
            ajaxSuccess: null,
            uploader: null,
            noCloseDialog: false
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please, seperate ClientSide scripting from ServerSide scripting. If you ask about jQuery, then try not to ask about RoR at same time. You are cutting down people, who will answer your question, to only those, who know both languages.

Comment: Wassup Deele? I would separate them if it were that easy, but for this one both are kinda intertwined - or rather I haven't quite figured out how to separate them. If you can give me a hint, then that would be awesome.

Comment: ClientSide gives info about what User is doing inside client. ServerSide is translating those orders, makes some actions, and responds to Client, making DOM change ClientSide appearance/content. Seperate one from another - if you have problems with how something is represented in ClientSide or server is receiving wrong answers from Client - that is ClientSide. If ClientSide is working correctly, but server side is not storing/editing/doing any action - that is ServerSide. You should have strict format for ServerSide, one function Adds comment, another Edits, same as for ClientSide.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a serverside return some value, that represents, if editing of comment was successfull, in that case, you have three options:

1. Make JavaScript refresh whole page (OK option)
2. Make serverside not only return success message, but also return new list of comments  (worst option)
3. With JavaScript, replace your comment container, with data, you entered in edit field (best option)

If you choose 3rd option, you should:

1. Add return value from server, if comment editing was successfull
2. Add inside ajax success statement, check, if return value is success value, if so, run a function
3. Add a function for JavaScript, that replaces comment container HTML, with value from edit  (or whatever you use).

Comment: I think, though, that this might be more of a Rails issue and less of a JS issue. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Deele, so I have narrowed it down `compv.comments.updated` doesn't have `xhr` defined. I agree with you about the 3rd option. That's what I am going for. Given the context of my code, how do I get the xhr issue sorted out ?